# Java code to create an array of array using simpleJSon

Tags: java, json, simplejson

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "PARAMORDER": [{
        "TAB1": [{
            "1": "Picture ID Source"
        }, {
            "2": "Place of Issuance"

        }],
        "TAB2": [{
            "1": "Picture ID Source"
        }, {
            "2": "Place of Issuance"

        }]
    }]
}
```

I am trying to create a JSON Array using java code which looks like the above format when it is parsed and retrieved. I am using org.json.simple API for this. However I am unable to create an array of array in JSON using java code. Can someone please share me a sample code which can construct the JSON in the above format.

Below is the sample code I tried which creates a json array:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject firstJson = new JSONObject();
JSONObject secondJson = new JSONObject();

firstJson.put("1", "Picture ID Source");
secondJson.put("1", "Picture ID Source");

jsonArray.add(firstJson);
jsonArray.add(secondJson);

System.out.println(jsonArray.toString);
```

This gives me the following JSON:

```
[{
    "1": "Picture ID Source"
}, {
    "1": "Picturesecond ID Source"
}]
```

I am unable to create a JSONArray of JSONArray. Can someone please help me with that?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First of all, we are not a question-and-answer site, code-writing service.  Second of all, that code does not produce that JSON.

Comment: I knew that code does not give the JSON which I need. I just wanted some suggestion like just a sample code to construct it and that is why I just posted here. Stack Over Flow has always helped me to enhance my skills and I also knew this is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you need a lot more code to create the intermediate levels, the structures can be added in a tree-like manner indefinitely. Also your top level in your sample is a JSON object, not an array.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
JSONArray paraArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject a = new JSONObject();
JSONArray tab1 = new JSONArray();
JSONObject source1 = new JSONObject();
source1.put("1", "Picture ID Source");
tab1.add(source1);
JSONObject source2 = new JSONObject();
source2.put("2", "Place of Issuance");
tab1.add(source2);
a.put("TAB1", tab1);
paraArray.add(a);

JSONObject b = new JSONObject();
JSONArray tab2 = new JSONArray();
JSONObject source3 = new JSONObject();
source3.put("1", "Picture ID Source");
tab2.add(source3);
JSONObject source4 = new JSONObject();
source4.put("2", "Place of Issuance");
tab2.add(source4);
b.put("TAB2", tab2);
paraArray.add(b);

root.put("PARAMORDER", paraArray);

System.out.println(root.toString());
```

Output

```
{"PARAMORDER":[{"TAB1":[{"1":"Picture ID Source"},{"2":"Place of Issuance"}]},{"TAB2":[{"1":"Picture ID Source"},{"2":"Place of Issuance"}]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam !! That idea has solved my problem :)
Thanks again !!